My Cypress tests are throwing CORS issues only when MS Clarity is enabled through our A/B Testing Tool
The Problem
When MS Clarity is enabled through our A/B Testing Tool, my CI/CD pipeline is throwing issues. Cypress says that an uncaught error was thrown from a cross-origin script. On production, however, I am not receiving these errors.
The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

  > Script error.

Cypress detected that an uncaught error was thrown from a cross origin script.

We cannot provide you the stack trace, line number, or file where this error occurred.

Check your Developer Tools Console for the actual error - it should be printed there.

It's possible to enable debugging these scripts by adding the crossorigin attribute and setting a CORS header.

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the uncaught:exception event.

It has no stack trace to view. This is the additional information that is presented to me within the console:
    at CommandQueue.run (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:163776:21)
    at CommandQueue.run (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150228:15)
    at $Cy.runQueue (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151152:14)
    at cy.<computed> [as visit] (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151234:12)
    at __stackReplacementMarker (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150660:13)
    at runnable.fn (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151413:19)
    at callFn (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104964:21)
    at ../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js.Runnable.run (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104951:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:158443:30
From previous event:
    at Object.onRunnableRun (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:158426:53)
    at $Cypress.action (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:147622:28)
    at Runnable.run (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:156382:13)
    at ../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js.Runner.runTest (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105623:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105749:12
    at next (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105532:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105542:7
    at next (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105444:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105510:5
    at timeslice (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:99436:27)

What I tried
I read the following docs:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Uncaught-exceptions-from-your-application
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Cypress-detected-that-an-uncaught-error-was-thrown-from-a-cross-origin-script

I also tried to google for this instance online, but I could neither find something on Stack Overflow, Google Search or on the GitHub repos of the individual tools that could be related to this.
I checked the network tab to see if there are any errors, but there were none.
I also don't want to just ignore the issue here within Cypress.
What I expect to happen
I want to have Clarity enabled, and it should not obstruct my CI/CD pipeline and throw issues.
